# v-bind an array in a menu value but get individual item in the array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hope you all can help here.

I have a drop-down menu that I'm using `v-bind` to assign an array to the selected value. See below-

```
<select v-model="selected" name="SKU[]"   @onChange>
  <option v-for="infos in data" v-bind:value="{ level: infos.stockLevel, SKU: infos.SKU }"  @change="onChange($event)" >{{infos.SKU}} </option>
</select>
```

There are multiple menus and I'm storing the selected options in `SKU[]` and then passing them to a form via a post.

The problem is my controller is now reading `SKU[]` as this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "[object Object]"
  1 => "[object Object]"
]
```

I want to store `infos.SKU` in `SKU[]`, not `object object`.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store javascript objects in html. You can use there only strings, so you should call `JSON.stringify()` method with your object and then pass into value. Than you will be able to use it as an object after `JSON.parse()`.
But the best case is to use another vue component for options or pass only id of object in value

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing an event in `@change` event, you can directly pass the selected `v-model` attribute and then push the data object into `SKU` data variable.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: [{
      stockLevel: 'Level 1',
      SKU: 'SKU 1'
    }, {
      stockLevel: 'Level 2',
      SKU: 'SKU 2'
    }, {
      stockLevel: 'Level 3',
      SKU: 'SKU 3'
    }, {
      stockLevel: 'Level 4',
      SKU: 'SKU 4'
    }],
    selected: '',
    SKU: []
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(selectedValue) {
      if (!JSON.stringify(this.SKU).includes(JSON.stringify(selectedValue))) {
        this.SKU.push(selectedValue);
      }
      console.log(this.SKU);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected" @change="onChange(selected)">
    <option 
            v-for="(infos, index) in data" 
            :key="index" 
            v-bind:value="{ level: infos.stockLevel, SKU: infos.SKU }"
            >
      {{infos.SKU}} 
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not sure how are you managing multiple selections because without using the `multiple` prop or any other way, at a time only a single value would be displayed as selected which seems vague from a "multiple-selection UI" perspective.

Secondly, there is no `@onchange` syntax, it should be either `onchange` or `@change`.

Third, the `@change` event should fire on the `select` element, not the option element.

At last, your `v-model` is what you are using to bind the selected element, then why not use that to track the selected element?

Here is the working demo-

```html
<html>
  <div id="app">
    {{ SKU }}<br>
    <select v-model="selected" @change="onChange">
      <option
        v-for="infos in data"
        :value="{ level: infos.stockLevel, SKU: infos.SKU }"
        >{{ infos.SKU }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!-- Don't forget to include Vue from CDN! -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: "#app", //Tells Vue to render in HTML element with id "app"
      data() {
        return {
          SKU: [],
          selected: null,
          data: [{
              stockLevel: "Stock level 1",
              SKU: "SKU 1",
            },
            {
              stockLevel: "Stock level 2",
              SKU: "SKU 2",
            },
          ],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        onChange() {
          // Do not push if already exists. I assumed "SKU" was a unique property.
          if (this.SKU.find(item => item.SKU == this.selected.SKU)) return;

          this.SKU.push(this.selected)
        },
      },
    });
  </script>
</html>
```